# Updating content with parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, updating

A while ago I asked a question and many of you helped me out. Thank you. I have another question to ask that has put me on hold in development. I have parse linked up to my app and can use push notifications and all. But I want to know how I can update content using parse directly to my app. Not physical app changes. But content wise. For example, say I have a movie app. I have a tableview and cells with all the movies. Say a new movie comes out. I don't want to update the app from the App Store just to add one new movie. I would like to add the new movie from parse and have it update to my app so that one new movie is in the list.  Have it all be online. Also. Since I'm new to back ends, I will eventually make my own code for the server (hopefully) but until then, I need to use parse. So. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I read the documentation and it never really directly spoke about updating table views. Just saving data and things I did not need to use at the time. I notice how my question has -2. Don't really know why. I was just asking an honest question.

Comment: You wouldn't need to update your app in the app store, you would simply just add more data to your parse database, then the next time your app pulls the data from the parse database it will load with the new data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at Parse's quick start page
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

Also check their iOS documentation
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

It's very straight forward, and will set you up in no time!

Answer (score 0):

**Parse** has something that you would extremely appreciate. If you choose the tap "Core". You will find a data browser. That thing is really powerful that you can just change whatever you can there. I think you should probably go ahead to play around that dashboard before implementing your applications. That tool is pretty straightforward. Also, they have data analytics tool. Tutorials are included also.